# What is the correct answer to this answered combinatorics problem?

Tags: combinatorics

In [this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/493221/), it was asked how many different ways we can arrange 4 managers and 3 employees in 7 seats around a circular table. One user said that there were 144 ways. I said there were 16. Whose answer is correct? Are we both wrong? Is it dependent on what is meant by "arrange"?

Comment: I don't think this qualifies as an own question. Therefore I downvoted.

Comment: Not the way we do things here. 

Comment: I don't get it: what's the OP supposed to do? To write a comment in his own old question, a comment very probably not many (or very few, in fact) people will see as it is a past question, and remain with the doubt? I think this is valid way to post a valid mathematics question, and unless someone explains to me why this is wrong I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: No reason to serial downvote. There are times when answers to a question conflict, and voting doesn't indicate any concensus on "which if any is right". So passerby-ers are likely to be confused, if they have the same question. So what to do? repost and risk being slammed with "DUPLICATE", or be straight and upfront with a link to the post in question and a point blank question regarding: "so what *is* correct here." Granted, I'd have rewritten the question itself with the conflicting answers and a link to the post in question, but cut some slack folks.

Comment: @DonAntonio + 1 I agree completely (you're post beat me to it!) Maybe the fodder for a meta-question about this sort of situation.

Comment: @DonAntonio The very least one can do, is to make the question immanent, that is, to restate the problem concisely, just as suggested by amWhy. Also, I'd probably searched or asked a question on meta on how to handle the situation.

Comment: Thanks @amWhy . Sometimes I don't see clearly why things have to be so stiff...

Comment: @K.Stm. , perhaps but then the OP's "sin" is a very, very minor one as not everybody seems to think the same. Perhaps it is a good idea, and a good suggestion to the OP, to re-post the whole question, though the link makes that unnecessary imo.

Comment: BTW, the question's been re-opened and I've upvoted it to "make things more even"...

Comment: BTW, I suck at combinatorics (among other things) so I won't even try to do this question...

Comment: @DonAntonio Downvotes aren't such a bad thing, they are no death sentence, or even a sentence to anything. I wasn't angry with Atul, nor, I believe, was anyone else. I just firmly believe that questions should be immanent since content on other questions might change – what if the other guy or girl deleted his or her answer? So therefore this question was a bad question for it didn't contain a real question. Now, it does contain a real question. Therefore I undownvoted.

Comment: A simple edit to the original question would bring it back to the front page. An edit pointing to the disagreement would have accomplished the same purpose as posting this non-question.

Comment: I think downvotes, in general, suck, and if I am to judge by many, many people's reactions sometimes to them, I'd say most of this site's users take them personally or almost. In this particular case the downvotes looked, imo, as serial attack on the poster, and more than remarkd that some trasgression was commited it already looked as punishment (as most downvote look to most people, btw). It's not a matter of being "angry" or being a punisher (?), but as amWhy wrote this usually indicates to most people the question sucks. About the immanent thing: I don't agree, but it's your opinion.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I can't see any moral, ethical, appliable advantage in editing an old question and bring it to the top over writing a question as the OP did, not to mention that many newbies (as the OP) may have no pale idea about this.

Comment: Seems to me that if all the managers are identical, and all the employees are identical, your answer may be right; but if it is possible to tell one manager from another, and one employee from another, the other answer may be right.

Comment: possible duplicate of [arrangement in a circle with a condition](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493221/arrangement-in-a-circle-with-a-condition)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by arrange.  Do you think all managers are interchangeable and all employees are interchangeable, or is an arrangement where you swap the seats of two employees different?  Are the seats numbered, so if we rotate everybody one place we get a different arrangement?  How about if we mirror the arrangement, so clockwise becomes counterclockwise-is that different?

If the people are interchangeable and the seats are not numbered, we must have a subsequence $EMME$ because two managers must sit together (there aren't enough employees to separate them) and a third is not permitted.  The only arrangements are then $MMEMMEE, MMEMEME$-$2$ of them.  If the seats are numbered, each of these can be rotated seven ways, giving $14$ arrangements.  If the seats are not numbered but the people are distinguishable, we can arrange the managers $4!=24$ ways and the employees $3!=6$ ways for each order, giving $2\cdot 24 \cdot 6=288$ ways.  Finally if the people are different and the seats are numbered, we multiply by $7$ to get $2016$ arrangements.

Answer (score 4):

For the record, the correct answer is $288$ (nobody had found it before I just answered the original question; Ross Millikan was close but his arithmetic fell prey to the gravitational attraction of a previous wrong answer).

Comment: Actually, the answer is 144 or 288 depends on whether you consider mirrored arrangement is same arrangement or not.

Comment: @achillehui: That is true, but I don't think anybody interpreted the question in that way. Also note that if counting just subsets of $4$ of the $7$ places modulo symmetry, including reflection symmetry does not divide the number by$~2$.